# How to turn off the capacitive buttons light on Samsung devices programmatically?

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, android-settings, samsung-mobile-sdk

I need to turn off the capacitive buttons light in my app.

I found this popular implementation

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "button_key_light", 0);
```

Sadly, I get this exception on more recent Samsung devices

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot keep your settings in the secure settings.
```

Is there a known way to implement something like this?

I have found [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.notquiteinsane.galaxybuttonlights) and it seems to work fine with even the most recent devices, so I tried to decompile it and could only find the same line of code I mentioned above, which I really don't understand. Maybe the decompilation process changed a saved String in the system to "button_key_light"?

Maybe it's because of more recent build tools?

So does anyone have a known way of getting it to work?
Or at least an explanation for why my current code doesn't work?

Comment: See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37070806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured this out.

It seems like you have to target sdk version 22 or lower to write system settings that are not predefined.

So in order to run

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "button_key_light", 0);
```

You have to add this to your app build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ...    
    targetSdkVersion 22
    ...
}
```

Comment: Working for Jelly Bean (4.3) but NOT working in Android M with SDK version 23. Any clue ?